# TFS Get list of all availble fields and values- rest api

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

In my visual studio (TFS), when I try to write a TFS query I am able to see a list of all possible fields(eg. Team, Work Item Type etc.) and in values, I am able to see a list of all possible values for that field.

Is there any way I can get a list of all such fields and values?
Eg. I want to get a list of all Work Item Type I have in my TFS, or I want to get a list of all Applications in my TFS.

I have tried going through TFS rest APIs, I could only find a way to get [work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) or iterations or area path.
I am looking for REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST API still doesn't support get allowedvalues in a field.

Currently, we can only use old .net API to get allowedvalues by getting an instance of class FieldDefinition and referencing the AllowedValues property.

You can get list of fields via this API:

```
http://{tfs_url/project}/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=4.1
```